# Strange behavior of UISwipeGestureRecognizer - micro freezing app

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a strange problem with Swiperecognizer.

I have spawning objects on screen.

```
let SpawnObject = SKAction.run({
        () in

        showobject()

    })

    let delay1 = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.9)
    let SpawnDelay1 = SKAction.sequence([SpawnObject,delay1])
    let SpawnDelayForever1 = SKAction.repeatForever(SpawnDelay1)
    self.run(SpawnDelayForever1)

    let distance = CGFloat(self.frame.height + 200)
    let moveObject = SKAction.moveBy(x: -distance, y: 0, duration: TimeInterval(0.004 * distance))
    let removeObject = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([moveObject,removeObject])
```

I have object with some physics (Object2, B.png is similar).

```
func showObject(){
    let texture =  SKTexture(imageNamed: "A.png")
    object = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
    object.name = "A"
    object.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.width)
    object.setScale(0.7)
    object.zPosition = 2
    object.run(moveAndRemove)

    object.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: texture.size())
    object.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Object
    object.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Object2
    object.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Object2
    object.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    object.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true


    addChild(object)
}
```

I have set swipe recognizer in touchesBegan

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        location = touch.location(in: self)
        node = self.atPoint(location)
        if node.name == "A" {
            //node.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: 1000, y: 0, duration: 1)).  //Here I try set action only to touch
            let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rightSlide(_:)))
            rightSwipe.direction = .right
            view!.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
        }
        else if node.name == "B" {
            //node.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: -1000, y: 0, duration: 1)).   //Here I try set action only to touch
            let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(leftSlide(_:)))
            leftSwipe.direction = .left
            view!.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
        }else {print ("Blank space")}
    }

}

func leftSlide(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    if node.name == "B" {
    node.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: -1000, y: 0, duration: 1))
    }else {print ("Bad swipe")}
    }
func rightSlide(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    if node.name == "A" {
    node.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: 1000, y: 0, duration: 1))
    }else {print ("Bad swipe")}
}
```

And now the problem. Objects are showing on screen, when I swipe on them, they disappear to side. Everything works fine until I swipe something about 50 objects away, after that every next swipe freeze app for microsecond, objects weird jumps a few pixels down (more swipes, more pixels) and back to their original position and after this weird behavior object swipe away. More swipes = bigger freeze and bigger jumps.

I try turn off physics and nothing. But when I change action directly to touch (no need swipe, just touch), app works fine forever. So there must be wrong swipe recognizer. Or not? I check CPU and MEMORY and CPU has 35% and memory are about 50MB. Nodes on screen max 20. FPS are 60 but when app freeze, it goes down to 58 (Like flickering).

Any suggestion? How to diagnose where is problem? Thanks!

Comment: It seems that you are adding gesture recognizers on every tap. Define a recognizer as a property of a scene in didMove(toView:) and remove it in willMove(fromView:).

Comment: I´m quite new in swift. Could you please tell me more? Or post some example? Thanks!

Comment: Checkout my answer...Let me know if you are still stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a recognizer every time in touchesBegan method, you should do the following:

1) Create an array to store all recognizers, so you can remove them later easily

2) Add recognizers only once. Note that recognizers are added to the view, not to the scene

3) Remove them when the scene is about to remove from a view

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene,SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


     var recognizers:[UIGestureRecognizer] = []

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {


        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameScene.leftSlide(recognizer:)))
        leftSwipe.direction = .left
        leftSwipe.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
        recognizers.append(leftSwipe)

         //do the same for other recognizers

    }

    func leftSlide(recognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        print("Swipe")
    }

//define other methods here to handle other recognizers...

  override func willMove(from view: SKView) {
    super.willMove(from: view)

    for recognizer in recognizers {
        self.view?.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    }
    recognizers.removeAll()
}
}
```

Comment: Yes! Works great! Probably removeGestureRecognizer is the magic :) Can I have last little question? When I start the app -> spawn first object -> first swipe on object not working -> second swipe works. After that, every swipe on new object works fine. Do you know why first swipe on first object not work? :( Thanks.

Comment: Check if your touch handling logic is correct. To chech if a swipe handler is called for the first time, put a break point or a print statement in it. But I would say your touch handling logic is wrong if you are experiencing what you have described.

Comment: I set up breakpoints to both swipes and works correctly, after first swipe app stops.

Comment: @LukasH. Then check your logic... You are going off topic by the way...